# WPF: Image as Background with Opacity Mask

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I haven't been able to get this to work, but this is what I envision:

Essentially, I want to have a control in WPF where the background is set to a left aligned image with an opacity mask that fades the right side of the image out into transparency (so that the parent's background color shows through)

Is this type of thing possible? Here's what I've tried:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <DockPanel.Background>                    
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="test.jpg" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" />
    </DockPanel.Background>
    <DockPanel.OpacityMask>
      <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5"/>
      </LinearGradientBrush>
    </DockPanel.OpacityMask>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This example should get you started.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="myImage" Source="test.jpg">
      <Image.OpacityMask>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5" >
          <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#00000000" />
          <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#FF000000" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
      </Image.OpacityMask>
    </Image>
    <VisualBrush x:Key="myBrush"  Visual="{StaticResource myImage}"/>
  </Grid.Resources>

  <DockPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Width="550"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Background="{StaticResource myBrush}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a partially transparent bitmap (png). That way you can have more complex transparency effects than just a gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Like this: (replace the underlying rectangle with any image u want)

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Rectangle Margin="187,91,147,101" Stroke="Black">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Margin="254,164,196,158" Stroke="Black" Fill="Red">
        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#00000000"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```